# Need equals Jsoup HTML document parser from in Gson

Tags: java, jsoup, gson

I have code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( HTMLstring);
Element  loginform = doc.getElementById( FormID);
Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag( "input");
for( Element inputElement : inputElements)
{
...
}
```

This work perfect.

I need delete Jsoup jar from my project. I find easy solution in Gson parser with this functions.
Please any references...

Comment: I thought Gson was a JSON parser? Does it parse HTML?

Comment: Yes Gson is JSON parser, but may be exist any HTML parsing solution with Gson and small functionality over Gson? I need reject jsop.jar from my project because it increase size of my project.

Comment: @TapaSave _because it increase size of my project_. I didn't know Jsoup was that heavy

Comment: @TapaSave jsoup.1.7.3.jar is heavy as 290 Ko...